# C# Null reference exception and StreamReader

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am getting null reference exception when reading data from my txt file.

```
     public class Appointments : List<Appointment>
        {
            Appointment appointment;

            public Appointments()
            {

            }

            public bool Load(string fileName)
            {
                string appointmentData = string.Empty;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    while((appointmentData = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        appointmentData = reader.ReadLine();
                        //**this is where null ref. exception is thrown** (line below)
                        if(appointmentData[0] == 'R')
                        {
                            appointment = new RecurringAppointment(appointmentData);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            appointment = new Appointment(appointmentData);
                        }
                        this.Add(appointment);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

`RecurringAppointment` inherits from `Appointments`. File exists, file location is correct. Funny thing is that program was working 30 min ago I've only changed Load method from below to what u can see above :

```
 public bool Load(string fileName)
        {
            string appointmentData = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                while((appointmentData = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    appointmentData = reader.ReadLine();
                    if(appointmentData[0] == 'R')
                    {
                        this.Add(appointment = new RecurringAppointment(appointmentData));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Add(appointment = new Appointment(appointmentData));
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Now it does not work in either case.

Comment: aside from anything else that's wrong you are calling readline twice....

Comment: Why do you read another line after the while? This will kill your application on the last line (if the number of lines is odd). Infact the last line will be read from the while but then the other ReadLine has nothing to read and returns null. Did you add a new line to your file?

Comment: Bad habits I guess :D. After removing extra appointmentData = reader.ReadLine(). I am getting index out of range error.

Comment: Something  in your file perhaps. (Of course if your file contains empty lines then reading the char at index [0] will throw) Please show some lines of your input file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code reads two times at each loop. This means that, if your file has an odd number of rows when you read the last line of the file, the check against null inside the while statement allows your code to enter the loop but the following ReadLine returns a null string. Of course trying to read the char at index zero of a null string will throw the NRE exception.

There is also the problem of empty lines in your file. If there is an empty line then, again reading at index zero will throw an Index out of range exception

You could fix your code in this way

```
public bool Load(string fileName)
{
    string appointmentData = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        while((appointmentData = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appointmentData))
            {
                if(appointmentData[0] == 'R')
                    this.Add(appointment = new RecurringAppointment(appointmentData));
                else
                    this.Add(appointment = new Appointment(appointmentData));
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great way to deal with file reading :D. Thank you for your input.Wish I could give you some +rep :(.